# How to convert an array of bits into text

Tags: java, arrays, text, bit

I had a string for eg "java education" which I have converted into bits. Now I have an array of bits. I want to convert it back into text. How to do this?

```
String s="Java Education";
char[] ch=s.toCharArray();
String g="  ";
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
for(char c:ch)
{
    g=Integer.toBinaryString((int)c);
    sb.append(ch);
}
char[] ch2= sb.toString.toCharArray();
```

I want to get back the text from the array ch2.

Comment: @BackSlash i have written the code for that above...by converting it to char array then using stringbuilder.

Comment: @R.J bits as in i have an array ch2 whose contents are 00110101010...so on

Comment: Looking at your current code, I really doubt if `ch2` contains bits. It contains the String "Java Education" multiple times(string.length() times) as a character array.

Comment: @R.J it contains bits but as chars...i.e 0101110...where eaqch bit is a char

Comment: I suggest you provide a sample where you specify what values are stored in the `ch2` and how exactly you want to convert them back.

Comment: @Manika R.J Is right, check your code, you are appending `ch`(which is the `char` array) to the `StringBuilder` instead of `g`

Comment: Also, if you look at your code closely, you can notice that in the `for` loop you're appending `ch` to the `StringBuilder` instead of `g` which I'm guessing is what you intended to do.

Comment: @Salman not exactly. In java, a `char` takes 2 bytes

Comment: yes @R.J sorry that is supposed to b g . i corrected it. I mistyped. Anyhow now my array ch2 contains chars which are 0s and 1s and i want to convert them into text. that is..i want to get back "java education" from 010101100111

Comment: @BackSlash True, `char ` in `Java` takes `16-bit` (`2-byte`). Refer to this documentation: [Java Basic Data Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm)

Comment: It is an array of characters. So, its an array of `bytes` not `bits`. Since each character is stored as two `byte`. Plus point for @BackSlash

Comment: okay. but the problem remains..please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DecodeBits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Java Education";
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : ch) {
            // Wen need a fix length
            String g = String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString((int) c)).replace(' ', '0');
            // this seems to be typo
            // sb.append(ch);
            sb.append(g);
        }
        char[] ch2 = sb.toString().toCharArray();
        int start = 0;
        while (start < ch2.length - 15) {
            char[] bits = Arrays.copyOfRange(ch2, start, start + 16);
            int cValue = Integer.parseInt(new String(bits), 2);
            char[] chars = Character.toChars(cValue);
            System.out.print(chars[0]);
            start += 16;

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation:

```
    String s="Java Education";
    char[] ch=s.toCharArray();
    String g="";
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    for(char c:ch)
    {
        g=Integer.toBinaryString((int)c);
        if(g.length()<8){
            for(int h=0; h<8-g.length(); h++){
                g="0"+g;
            }
        }
        sb.append(g);
        sb.append(',');
    }
    char[] ch2= sb.toString().toCharArray();
    String[] s3 = new String(ch2).split(",");

    for(String t: s3){
        String d="";
        for(int x=t.length()-1; x>=0; x--) d+=t.charAt(x);
        t=d;
        int num=0;
        for(int j=0; j<t.length(); j++){
            num+=Integer.parseInt(""+t.charAt(j))*Math.pow(2, j);
        }
        System.out.print((char)num);
    }
```